# Is there a way to format a String created from a list of user input to have the number of each new line numbered from 1:

Tags: python, string

Example:

1. First item
2. Second item
3. Third item
4. 4th item

```
item = []

while len(item) <= i: ## i is user input
    iapp = input("$:")
    item.append(iapp)
item = '\n'.join(item)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using a for loop, this way you have an index that you can add to the beginning of each input. (For loops are more efficient too)

```
item = ""
for j in range(1,i+1):
    iapp = input("$:")
    item += str(j) + ". " + iapp + "\n"
```

You can also skip the item list entirely and append the inputs onto a string variable, along with the `\n` escape sequence.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Sorry, this was my first answer :)

Comment: Good job! A deserved +1 for a well written answer.